# VSCode: Change Background Color of Select Box

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to change background of this `select box`, but i didn't find any properties for this.

[image]

In the above example, the `select box` has dark color, how I can change it?

*I know I should add particular property to the `workbench.colorCustomizations`, but I don't know what to add.*

Comment: look at the list of possible color names and pick/try the ones that are possible candidates, the number of them is finite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `dropdown.background` property in your setting.json file. Specifically,

```json
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "dropdown.background": "#ff0000" // changes to red background
    },
```